# <LI> order not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a site that shows 3 social icons in a list. There is some code in the header that changes the location of these social icons on any other page other than the homepage. For some reason, the order of the social icons is different on the homepage vs the other pages.

The order I'd like is Facebook, Twitter, Instagram..

Any idea why the order is changing?

Here is the code in the header:

```
 </div><div id="social-container"><ul id="social-icons">
 <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/facebook.png" border="0" height="50px" width="50px"></a> </li>
<li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/twitter.png" border="0" height="50px" width="50px"></a> </li>
 <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/instagram.png" border="0" height="50px" width="50px"></a></li>
 </ul>
```

css:

```
#social-container {
    height:100%;
    z-index:-100;
}

#social-icons {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:30px;
}


#social-icons li {
    float:left;
    display: inline;
    list-style-type:none; 
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    bottom:0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

and then this qualifier in the header:

```
<?php if ( is_home() ) { ?>
 <style type="text/css">
    #social-icons li {float:right; display: inline;list-style-type:none; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; width:50px;height:50px;text-decoration: none;}
    #social-icons {width:100%; position:absolute;top:35px;}
}

    </style>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: because that's how float left and right work...your best bet is to wrap them in an element and float that instead of the list items

Comment: you can't use float:right and display:inline at the same time. float:left/right only works on display:block elements, and if you omit it the browser will turn them into blocks automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `text-align:right;` `instead of float:right;`

As said below, it is because of the floating of the elements. The first li element will float to the right first and the rest follow suit, this is what gives the impression that they are "reversed".

Comment: hmm.. text-align:right doesn't send these elements to the right hand side of my browser like float:right did

Comment: It will send them to the right hand side of their container which is the ul, try `text-align:right;` on the ul element

Answer (score 0):

It is due to this rule

```
#social-icons li {float:right;}
```

A float right reverses the order of elements (in your case all li elements)